# Results called before closing connection are not showing / error: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database

Tags: python, sqlite

The following code is throwing the error 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.'

Considering that I close the connection **after** the queries are done, I don't understand why this is happening.

```
import sqlite3

def database():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return connection

def _index():
    connection = database()
    posts = connection.execute('SELECT P.title, P.content, P.created, U.username FROM posts P JOIN users U ON P.author_id = U.id').fetchall()
    users = connection.execute('SELECT U.fullname as "username", C.fullname as "committeename" FROM users U JOIN committees C ON U.committee_id = C.id')
    connection.close()
```

I was trying to query the users database and posts database (2 queries) and then close the connection but an error is happening that doesn't let me do this.

Comment: I notice you do not have a fetchall() at the end of the "users" query. Maybe that needs to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i had not added a .fetchall() clause at the end of the query.

Corrected code:

```
import sqlite3

def database():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return connection

def _index():
    connection = database()
    posts = connection.execute('SELECT P.title, P.content, P.created, U.username FROM posts P JOIN users U ON P.author_id = U.id').fetchall()
    users = connection.execute('SELECT U.fullname as "username", C.fullname as "committeename" FROM users U JOIN committees C ON U.committee_id = C.id')
    connection.close()
```